# Hide JSP Included Page On Load

Tags: jsp, include, hide

I have two jsp files: `main.jsp` and `formDialog.jsp`. In `main`, I have included `formDialog` and on button click, this will open as a dialog. This is working fine, however, the contents of `formDialog` (input fields of the form) is displaying on my main page. How can I hide `formDialog` on page load and only display it when the dialog is called/opened?

**main.jsp**

```
<div id="formDialogDiv">
        <jsp:include page="formDialog.jsp"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn").on("click",(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: "<c:url value='val'/>",
         success: function(){
         $('#formDialogDiv').dialog({
               modal: true
         });
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

**formDialog.jsp**

```
<div id = "formBody">
    <form id="newForm">
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I just added a simple `style="display: none;"` to `formDialogDiv` and that was it.

```
<div id="formDialogDiv" style="display: none;">
    <jsp:include page="formDialog.jsp"/>
</div>
```